# App file size issues..use of .WebP format images

Tags: resize, dpi, bucket, webp

I have run into file size problems in an app I am currently working on.
So I have converted all my images to the WebP format and reduced the file sizes  remarkably .
However when attempting to batch process these images to fill the appropriate dpi buckets the pixel densities remain at 72 dpi.
All the buckets are filled with 72 dpi images.
Is it acceptable to simply paste all the images into the project/app/ drawable resource folder and forgo the buckets altogether ?

Comment: What are *"buckets"* in this context, please?

Comment: The  buckets I referred to are the containers for hdpi ,mdpi.xhdpi ,xxhdpi and xxxhdpi images.